# Can I find unique dwellers in the outlands using the radio station?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was wondering, after I've received a unique dweller (Three Dog) in a lunchbox, if there is a way to attract those special/unique dwellers even through the radio stations from the outlands.

Do you ever have received some of the unique dwellers from the outlands?

Comment: I have the same question and I am not sure if they are an exclusive of the lunch boxes. I know I have gotten the rare gear from exploring which can also come out of the lunch boxes but so far, no rare/specific people have come to my vault. Interesting to see if they are only from the boxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm that you may attract unique dwellers on the radio as I got Butch just yesterday.

Comment: Also, if you think an existing answer is correct, the best way to show it is to upvote it.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with his answer, he has addressed a part of the question the other answer didn't (unique dwellers via radio), and didn't address any other answers. I don't see that it's been edited either...?

Comment: Having someone who encounter that submit a screenshot would go a long way clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

I have found between 20 and 30 Dwellers via Radio Station signals, and none of them have been unique characters.  From what I have read on other sites, it appears unique dwellers can only be obtained via lunchboxes.  If I see or find out otherwise, I will change this answer.

As an interesting aside: "unique" characters are not actually unique. Somewhat amusingly, you can find multiples of the same unique character in lunchboxes.

Comment: I have 4 different (not so different) Eulogy Jones walking around my vault. So much for unique.

Comment: You could rename them to be unique. Did all 4 have the same starting stats? Same equipment?

Comment: Interesting to know. Well, they are some kind of unique like unique weapons in nearly all other games. :-D

Comment: That's why they're called [**Legendary** dwellers](http://www.bethblog.com/2015/06/30/fallout-shelter-a-legendary-dweller-from-the-commonwealth/comment-page-1/#comment-424313), and not "unique". :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can get rare dwellers on the radio the only purpose for dwellers from the radio is to get new DNA in your vault. You can breed for better dwellers and their are some special pet that give +1-3 to the stats of a child and their are explorer quests and quests that give higher stat dwellers and breeding rare with rare seem to produce some more rares and i have had some luck with breeding new arrivals with the highest same stat to each other.