# In fallout shelter, after the quests update, can you get legendary dwellers from radio tower?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In fallout shelter, can you get [legendary dwellers](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_characters#Legendary_dwellers) from [radio room](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Radio_studio) **after the update which added quests**?

I heard that with the new update that added quests you also can now get legendary dwellers from the radio room. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Possibly related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225157/can-i-find-unique-dwellers-in-the-outlands-using-the-radio-station

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to say, but **no**.

In [this developer blog](http://www.bethblog.com/2015/06/30/fallout-shelter-a-legendary-dweller-from-the-commonwealth/comment-page-1/#comment-424325) the same question was asked and the answer states that legendary dwellers can only be obtained through lunch boxes.

> - Alvaro Jauregui said on Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 6:41 pm:
>     Can you get Preston Garvey (or any Legendary Dweller) through the Radio Sation? Are the Legendaries Lunch Box exclusive?
>
>   - Matt Grandstaff said on Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 8:11 pm:
>       Legendary Dwellers are in Lunchboxes only

Also, as for 2016-09-07, the Fallout Wiki-s [entry on legendary Fallout Shelter characters](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_characters#Legendary_dwellers) states that:

> Rare dwellers are found in lunchboxes.

Comment: By the way, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/227898/126370 states that you can. Strange.

Comment: Well Preston Garvey is a legendary dweller and can be obtained via quest, not lunchbox.

Comment: @OrangeDog if you have more relevant info you can edit the answer and add it there. :)

Comment: @IvanKolmychek but I'm disputing the answer, not adding to it.

Comment: @OrangeDog technically, you don't, as your information doesn't contradict short answer - that you can get one legendary dweller **through quest** doesn't mean you can get legendary dwellers **through radio room** (as the question asks), just that in **this one** case legendary dwellers are not unique to lunchboxes.

Comment: It demonstrates that the evidence presented is incorrect.

Comment: @OrangeDog the information from http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/227898/126370 on the other hand states that you can attract legendary dwellers through radio room, and, if that will get more proof, can be used to dispute this answer.

Comment: @IvanKolmychek that answer holds no actual evidence, proof, or sources. Maybe since an update this is now possible but it is also likely that they could have opened a lunch box without thinking about it, found the dweller and concluded they were attracted by the radio station.

Comment: I agree with @micoxion. The post with the proof you have is from over a year ago.  This question is about the newest update that recently update.  I've herd from different posts that you can legendary dwellers but haven't seen any videos/pictures of it actually happening.  I've also been running test on my game and haven't gotten any good results.